# Parent process doesn't do the default action after receiving SIGINT

Tags: bash, shell-script, signals

I did 2 tests about SIGINT using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in bash.

### Test 1

Both parent script and child script set a handler by `trap`.

```bsh
# !/bin/bash
# Parent.sh
trap 'echo "I handled the SIGINT in Parent.sh and expect the script going ahead."' SIGINT
echo 1.1
./Child.sh
echo 1.2
```

```bsh
# !/bin/bash
# Child.sh
trap 'echo "I handled the SIGINT in Child.sh and expect the script going ahead."' SIGINT
echo 2.1
sleep 1000000000
echo 2.2
```

```
/tmp:$ ./Parent.sh
1.1
2.1
^CI handled the SIGINT in Child.sh and expect the script going ahead.
2.2
I handled the SIGINT in Parent.sh and expect the script going ahead.
1.2
```

The output quite tallies with my expectation.

### Test 2

Only the child script set a handler by `trap`.

```bsh
# !/bin/bash
# Parent.sh
# trap 'echo "I expect I will be terminated immediately after Child.sh died."' SIGINT
echo 1.1
./Child.sh
echo "sleep started"
sleep 5
echo "sleep finished"
echo 1.2
```

```bsh
# !/bin/bash
# Child.sh
trap 'echo "I handled the SIGINT in Child.sh and expect the script going ahead."' SIGINT
echo 2.1
sleep 1000000000
echo 2.2
```

```
/tmp:$ ./Parent.sh
1.1
2.1
^CI handled the SIGINT in Child.sh and expect the script going ahead.
2.2
sleep started
sleep finished
1.2
```

I expected the `Parent.sh` should immediately terminated(as the default action about SIGINT) after `Child.sh` died.

But it seems `Parent.sh` received an SIGINT, but it ignored it.

Why it could be this?

Answer (score 3):

That happens because of ["Wait and Cooperative Exit"](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html) (WCE) which `bash` implements.

When bash receives a `SIGINT` signal while waiting for a child, it will only kill itself if the child died because of that signal, not if the child exited. A parent process can determine from the exit status of the child whether it exited or died because of an unhandled signal -- see the `WIF*` macros in the [`wait(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) manpage.

A simpler example:

```
bash -c 'sh -c "trap exit INT; read p"; echo DONE'
<ctrl-C>
DONE
```

And with the **`dash`** shell, which doesn't implement WCE:

```
dash -c 'sh -c "trap exit INT; read p"; echo DONE'
<ctrl-C>
<no DONE, parent script was killed outright>
```

See the similar [Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230421/unable-to-stop-a-bash-script-with-ctrlc), and the [kludge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/515355/308316) I've proposed as a work-around.